# How to run top - linux command in Java?

Tags: java, linux, console-application

I want to create a console application with all the functions of the top command, but through java
how to create this consol app with the top command through java professionally

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be like this one:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
```

Comment: and how about the consol app with top command

Comment: @jonasgarden the same